# Function with 2 variables $ f(x,y)=(x-y)e^{xy} $

Tags: calculus

Find minimum and maximum  of the next function:

$$ f(x,y)=(x-y)e^{xy} $$

In the square:

$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
-1\leq x\leq 1 \\ -1\leq y\leq 1 
\end{matrix}\right. $$

I have found that $f(x,y)$ doesn't have maxima and minima. by that I mean without looking at the square, just at the function.

Comment: How did you "find" that? What did you do? That square is a compact set and the given functuion is continuous everywherem, thus by Weierstrass theorems not only the function us bounded there but it also attains its maximum and minimum.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maxima+f%28x%2Cy%29+%3D+%28x+-+y%29e^%28xy%29%2C+-1%3C%3Dx%3C%3D1%2C+-1+%3C%3Dy%3C%3D1

Comment: @Timbuc, I edited my question. I meant that $f(x,y)$ doesn't have maximx and minima without looking at the square.

Comment: @TTaJTa4 Who cares what happens **not in the square**??

Comment: @Timbuc, It was question before this one, so I thought it might help somehow.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}&f_x=e^{xy}\left(1+xy-y^2\right)=0\iff y^2-xy=1\\{}\\&f_y=e^{xy}\left(-1+x^2-xy\right)=0\iff x^2-xy=1\end{align}$$

Substracting both equations above we get $\;(x-y)(x+y)=0\implies x=\pm y\;$ , and we have lots of critical points.

Now:

$$\begin{align}&f_{xx}=e^{xy}\left(2y+xy^2-y^3\right)\\{}\\&f_{xy}=e^{xy}\left(2x+x^2y-xy^2\right)\\{}\\&f_{yy}=e^{xy}\left(-2x+x^3-x^2y\right)\end{align}$$

Evaluate now the Hessian at critical points and you'll see there're lots of max.-min. points *inside* the square. Finally, you will have to compare this with values of the function on the square's perimeter.

Disclaimer: Check carefully the above calculations, which only come to serve you as a guide. There might be mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Solving $\nabla f=0$ you'll pretty quickly find only two solutions $(\pm\sqrt2/2,\mp\sqrt2/2)$, which are both saddles.  Now look at the boundary, for example $x=1$ and $-1\leq y\leq1$. Here $f(1,y)=(1-y)e^y$, which has a maximum in $y=0$ and minima in $y=\pm1$. Treat the rest of the boundary in a similar way.